# Python: Create a try except general purpose function

Tags: python, error-handling, try-catch, exec, except

For a parsing script I need to use in many places try except blocks. I thought I can use a general purpose function which use as the parameter the expression that need to be evaluated.

I cannot used the expression directly as a parameter because it can trow an error before entering in try except block:

```
def exception(a, nr_repeat=5):
if nr_repeat != 0:
    try:
        a
        nr_repeat = 0
    except ExceptionType:
        exception(a, nr_repeat-1)
```

So, I start passing a , the expression to evaluate as a string, and use exec:

```
def exception(a, nr_repeat=5):
 if nr_repeat != 0:
    try:
        exec(a)
        nr_repeat = 0
    except ExceptionEx:
        exception(a, nr_repeat-1)
```

which is working if the expression doesn't use variables. If it uses variables, even if I pass then to the function is not working.

```
def exception(a, nr_repeat=5,*args):
 if nr_repeat != 0:
    try:
        exec(a)
        nr_repeat = 0
    except ExceptionEx:
        exception(a, nr_repeat-1)
```

function:

```
exception("print('blue)") - working
exception("data.split('/')") - not working
```

ExceptionEx is just a placeholder for different exceptions

Comment: The typical way of doing such things is by passing callables around, not strings (e. g. lambdas or function pointers).  Do you have specific requirements which make you use strings holding code instead?

Comment: If anything, pass a `lambda` and run it, not `exec`ing a string. However, if you often need to run arbitrary code which should be retried 5 times if it raises an error... that seems like a very weird \*cough\*misguided\*cough\* approach. How much of this is placeholder sample code and how much of it is serious?

Comment: Where is data supposed to be coming from? The more I look at your code the more I think there is a better way to do what you are actually trying to do

Comment: You could also make your own context manager instead, I guess?

Comment: @deceze Repetitive trying to do something is a common approach in environments designed for failure, e. g. networks or similar.  If I cannot reach that server right now, I retry in a second, then in 5 seconds, then in 30, 180, 3600.  Only then I give up and report a failure.  (At least that's one way of doing it, depending on the circumstances, of course, but there's a usecase.)

Comment: Don't use recursion here; you're unnecessarily using up stack space. Instead, put the `try` statement in a for loop, handling the exit conditions as necessary.

Comment: the script is testing/gathering data on a server with loading issues, and I need to reload the page in some cases multiple times, until all the elements are loaded; The code that you see is a simple version of the real code - the for loop has some limitations this is why I used recursion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried passing in a lambda function?

```
exception(lambda: data.split('/'))
```

and inside of your function:

```
def exception(a, nr_repeat=5):
if nr_repeat != 0:
    try:
        a()
        nr_repeat = 0
    except ExceptionType:
        exception(a, nr_repeat-1)
```

The lambda will not be evaluated until you call it.